# Connecting to SQL Server with SQL Server account and encrypted password and executing invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Would really appreciate some help. I have a PowerShell script which I use to update columns in a SQL Server table. When this uses a domain account it works fine.

However, I want to run during user login, and use a SQL Server account, not Windows account, but I can't figure out why it isn't working.

When the key/txt file uses the domain account, no problems. But when replace with SQL Server account details, no go.

```
$SQLUser = "Username"
$SQLPasswordFile = "\\pathto\UserPW.txt"
$SQLKeyFile = "\\pathto\UserPW.key"
$SQLkey = Get-Content $SQLKeyFile
$SQLMyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $SQLUser, (Get-Content $SQLPasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $SQLkey)
$SQLCredentials = Get-Credential -Credential $SQLMyCredential
$SQLSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "uhpkpdb01" -Credential $SQLCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session $SQLSession -ScriptBlock {
$exist = Invoke-Sqlcmd "select count(1) from [table] where USER_NAME = '$($args[0])'" -ServerInstance "SERVERNAME"
if ($exist.column1 -eq "1") {
Invoke-Sqlcmd "UPDATE [table] SET PASSWORD = '$($args[1])' WHERE USER_NAME = '$($args[0])'"
Write-Host "Account Updated"  }
else {
Write-Host "User Does Not Exists"}} -ArgumentList $env:USERNAME, "PASSWORD"
Remove-PSSession $SQLSession
```

I am getting

> New-PSSesion : Connecting to remote server  failed with : The user name or password is incorrect.

I can connect using the SQL Server account to SSMS and open and update table.
I must be passing the user name incorrectly, but can't figure out how to do it properly.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the `-Username` and `-Password` parameters of [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a `PSCredential` object that contains your SQL Login to `Invoke-Command`. The only thing that command understands is Windows Credentials.

You can pass and call the `Invoke-SqlCmd` command directly from your own machine if you have the module installed.

If you need to use the SQL Login on a remote session you will have to pass that credential object into the remote session so it can be utilized within your script block.

Comment: Thank you for this reply.
I did see that installing the SQLServer module would let me run the command as mentioned. However, as this script will be run by every computer in the company at some point in time, I didn`t consider this as an option.
Not sure how to do the last part that you mentioned.

This will be a script that will be called during login at least once every 3 months.